# Dropbox Sync without the Sync API

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, dropbox

As a background I have been looking to implement syncing with Dropbox within my application. It will deal with multiple files residing in folders across a users Dropbox.

Initially the Sync API seemed perfect for this however it does not allow the app to have Full Dropbox Access which is a must. I considered the 'File type' permissions type but some of the file types that my app will need access to [are not listed as choices](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions).

Are there any alternatives to the Sync API which give Full Dropbox Access or will I be needing to write a solution based upon the Core API to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What file types do you need? We (Dropbox) do add new file types over time, so we're always looking for feedback.

For Full Dropbox access, yes, you'll have to use the Core API.

Comment: File types related to iOS and Mac programming. I notice `.c`, `.h` and  `.m`are already listed under Text files. Other's that come to mind which aren't listed would be `.xib`, `.nib` and `.storyboard` file types. I wouldn't expect those to be on there as they are quite specialised file types. Might I ask why the Sync API does not allow Full Dropbox access?